# Eclipse RSE: how get to know that the command already complete

Tags: java, eclipse, ssh, eclipse-plugin, openssh

I have the working eclipse plugin (internal) in version E3.3.2. Now I should to upgrade  eclipse to E4.3.2. In E3.3.2 I use Remote System Explorer (RSE) v_2.0.3. All working correctly. 
But in E4.3.2 with RSE v3.0.7 I have problem.
In 98% I cannot to finish my task (haven't event that remote shell is finished) and after "timeout" time I see 'Timeout exception', but all commands were finished successfully (by logs).

I have a `ScriptRunnerJob` class which extend `org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job` and implement `org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.IJobChangeListener`.

```
private class ShellEventsListener implements ISystemResourceChangeListener {
    public void systemResourceChanged(ISystemResourceChangeEvent event) {
        if (event.getType() == ISystemResourceChangeEvents.EVENT_REFRESH) {
            Object parent = event.getParent();
            if (parent instanceof IRemoteCommandShell) {
                ScriptRunnerJob scriptRunner = findScriptByShell((IRemoteCommandShell) parent);
                if (scriptRunner != null) {
                    scriptRunner.refreshScriptOutput();
                }
            }
        } else if (event.getType() == ISystemResourceChangeEvents.EVENT_COMMAND_SHELL_FINISHED) {
            Object source = event.getSource();
            if (source instanceof IRemoteCommandShell) {
                ScriptRunnerJob scriptRunner = findScriptByShell((IRemoteCommandShell) source);
                if (scriptRunner != null)
                    scriptRunner.notifyShellFinished();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

When I get event `EVENT_COMMAND_SHELL_FINISHED` - my script is finished successfully, but it happen rarely. I'm working with this issue few days and haven't any ideas. I'm not sure that this problem in RSE, but I don't know why it happening.

On server OpenSSH v1.4.5

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it in `org.eclipse.rse.internal.subsystems.shells.servicesubsystem.OutputRefreshJob.java`
add verification for output. In not changed - task should be finished.